# Splitting an array to the required format

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I have an array in Perl like this,

```
my @a = (
    '12345 abcd efgh ijkl mnop',
    '23456 asdf sdfse ert vsfg',
    '56706 isdua sdf sef mnvsdf',
)
```

I need to store this in following manner

1. First column alone in a separate variable separated by commas `,` like this `12345,23456,56706`
2. First two columns separated by colons `:` which are in turn separated by commas `,` like this `12345:abcd,23456:asdf,56706:isdua`

I was trying the first case but I couldn't find the solution

```
foreach my $s (@a){
    my @entries = split(/ /, $s); 
    my $_p = $entries[0]; 
    $csv1 = join(',', $_p);
}
```

I am getting only the last value `56706`

I used `$csv2 = $csv2 . "," . $_p;` and I got `,12345,23456,56706`

Could someone tell me how to get `12345,23456,56706` also the second case?

Comment: `12345:abcd,23456:asdf,56706:isdua` or `12345,23456,56706` which output you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the length of the accumulating variable to know whether you're in the first iteration of the loop, and add the comma only if you aren't.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ('12345 abcd efgh ijkl mnop',
             '23456 asdf sdfse ert vsfg',
             '56706 isdua sdf sef mnvsdf',
);

my ($first_one, $first_two);
for my $element (@array) {
    my @entries = (split ' ', $element)[ 0, 1 ];
    $first_one .= (length $first_one ? ',' : '') . $entries[0];
    $first_two .= (length $first_two ? ',' : '') . "$entries[0]:$entries[1]";
}

print $first_one, "\n", $first_two, "\n";
```

Do you really want to accumulate the results in variables, though? Don't you want to print them to files instead? If yes, it might even be possible to process the input line by line, instead of loading it to an array.

Comment: The answer you gave was the one expecting. I am new to perl. Could you please tell why I was not able to use join?

Comment: @VinuShankar: You were overwriting $csv1 in each iteration. You can use `$first_one = join ',', $first_one // (), $entries[0];` of course.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by using `map` to build an array of the first two values from each line. After that it's simply a matter of applying `join` to the appropriate mapping of the new list

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @a = (
    '12345 abcd efgh ijkl mnop',
    '23456 asdf sdfse ert vsfg',
    '56706 isdua sdf sef mnvsdf',
);

my ($s1, $s2);

{
    my @pairs = map [ ( split )[0,1] ], @a;

    $s1 = join ',', map $_->[0], @pairs;

    local $" = ':';
    $s2 = join ',', map "@$_", @pairs;
}

say $s1;
say $s2;
```

#### output

```
12345,23456,56706
12345:abcd,23456:asdf,56706:isdua
```